# How to get Object ID for dynamically created Label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to get Object ID for dynamically created Label?? As I have to translate Label text for other languages.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need Object ID for translation? To translate app, you generate strings file where all your localizable strings are and you translate that. App should pick correct strings file automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can translate text from app using String file. In string file we can store strings we want to translate.
Ex:
Localizable.string(Hindi)

```
"translate" = "अनुवाद करना";
```

Localizable.string(English)

```
"translate" = "translate"
```

As we run app, app automatically store selected language translations from file.
`Ex.`
`[[Localisator sharedInstance] setLanguage:[language];`

Answer (score 2):

Object ID is created by the interface builder and interface builder use it internally, there is no such property of `UIView` which gives you object id. Hence you can't access it via code (dynamically) regardless whether view is created on storyboard or at run time.